# Fluid CSS layout, one big centered div over background

Tags: css, layout, html, fluid

I would like to do a web design that consists in a floating fluid layout consisting on 2 divs over a background image: A main content layout centered and a menu one that is overlapped but relatively positioned over the left part of te content div.

How can I get that so its fluid and seen in any resolution? Which min/max-width do you recommend me?

```
browser window -> 100%
====================
     backgrnd      |
   -------------   |
   |           |   |
 |--|          |   |
 |M | content  |   |
 |__|          |   |
   |-----------|   |
   |__footer___|   |
___________________|


body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:80px; 
    color:yellow; 
    background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;
    font-size: 65%; 
}
```

Background should be occupying always the screen

```
.centraldiv {
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 775px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 80px;
}

.menudiv {
    position: relative?
    width: 100px;       
}
```

Am I going in a good way?

EDIT: No need to actually resolve it, just appointing me if I am assuming good approach (all examples in internet I find for fluid layouts are multicolumn, and the fews which arent, dont use a central panel at all (if you know some resource for this it is enough!). Thanks!

Comment: Why a negative vote? Could you explain it please, so I know what I am doing wrong

Comment: if you want it on all resolutions, including mobile devices, then you should inform yourself about media queries

Comment: Thats nice feature! Ill use it! Though I am not sure is particularly useful for skeleton layout (I am trying to do it percentual so it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with percentages is basic (but not required) to produce a good responsive layout, [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) are definitely indicated if you [really want the content to fit virtually any screen](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/the-infinite-grid/).

You should also start thinking in `em`s for both [layout](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/) and [text](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/).

---

Usually, you should start with a simple layout where every content block fills the width of the window: your 100px menu on a smartphone would occupy about a third of the screen!

```
====================
     backgrnd      |
   -------------   |
   |   menu    |   |
   |-----------|   |
   |           |   |
   |  content  |   |
   |           |   |
   |-----------|   |
   |__footer___|   |
___________________|
```

Simply keep them at `display:block;`:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 62.5% = ~10px = 1em */
    margin:0; 
    padding:8em; 
    color:yellow; 
    background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;
}
#centraldiv, #menudiv {
    padding:2em 0;
}
```

Then, play around with your browser window until you find a point where there is enough horizontal space to move the menu to the left:

```
@media screen and (min-width:40em){
    #centraldiv {
        width:90%;
    }
    #menudiv {
        float:left;
        /* etc... */
    }
}
```

...and so on. Percentages are ok, but it's not that simple.

Comment: Men your answer is AWESOME!. Just one question. Do You recommend me then to use em instead of percents?

Comment: @user1352530 it depends on the content ... however, i suggest you to begin with percentages

Comment: Sorry the last question, how do I manage the overlapping by menu's div. With float:left and current settings, menu appears just under central div not floating

Comment: Sorry my english I meant below not under :)

Comment: @user1352530 well, you can try something like `position:relative; top:25em; left:-5em;` or `top:-25em;` if the menu comes after contents

Comment: ehehe i'm not a "pro" @user1352530 but you're welcome! good coding

Answer (score 2):

The comment about media queries is the way to go.  In your example you set width,min-width, and max-width, which is also incorrect.  Set-up a desktop version for anything over 1280px, using only % widths.  Then start to overlay a media query for anything below your desired desktop width, so perhaps below 900px, then step it down at that point.

Read More: [Mozilla Developer's : Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) - [CSS Tricks : Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Edit: CSS Tricks is a responsive layout as well, play with your browser window to test it.